# Is forwardRef mandatory while creating NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, controlvalueaccessor

I have a custom input component which implements ControlValueAccessor with providers declared as follows. It seems to work fine. In all the tutorials I could find on the internet, forwardRef was being used extensively whenever NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR is provided

Is it safe to send the following code to production ?

```
providers: [{
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: CustomInputComponent,  //Notice I omitted forwardRef here and it works fine
  multi: true
}]
```

Answer (score 6):

`forwardRef` enables Angular to inject a dependency before it is defined. In this case, if this providers array is defined inside the `@Component` decorator for a custom input component as you mentioned, **it will work since decorators are applied after the class is defined**.

Basically, **you can remove `forwardRef` as long as you are only using it to reference a component inside the decorator for that same component.**

[See here for in depth reading](https://indepth.dev/what-is-forwardref-in-angular-and-why-we-need-it/)

Answer (score 4):

The goal of `forwardRef` is to delay access to a class that is not defined at the time of execution current code.

**It is not mandatory for your case** because TypeScript [transforms](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/AIYQ9gtgDmB2CmsAuAKA3gKAARYM7wBt4BjJMAJwC4sByAQyigFpiBXXMiJgS1ilaQ0ANNixJ40AnXHUaAHl78kWAPQA+AmGJ0C1NGgBuOgL7HhoqOTAHuAE3jlc1ANqicmHJ6yXrd+NQA5AHEAfQA1AEEAGQBVAFEQiJAQOIBlVIB5ACURLxx2eDiAD24OXgBzahB2TgBJPgFwaDhEJFy8iFYCJG5qJHJWeDcsY1EAXQxjAEosDHgimHJlYilcXCxqjkh6pSaYBGR3DEmMIA) your code in a way when **execution of decorator goes after class definition**.

```ts
let CustomInputComponent = /** @class */ (() => {
    var CustomInputComponent_1;
    let CustomInputComponent = CustomInputComponent_1 = class CustomInputComponent {
    };
    CustomInputComponent = CustomInputComponent_1 = __decorate([
        Component({
            selector: 'app-custom-input',
            template: '<input />local: {{val}}',
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
                    useExisting: CustomInputComponent_1, // already defined!!!
                    multi: true
                }
            ]
        })
    ], CustomInputComponent);
    return CustomInputComponent;
})();
```